# Outputting geoJSON with arcpy.FeaturesToJSON_conversion tool of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, geojson, arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.0 and I've updated my system path to point to the version of Python (3.5.3) which shipped with ArcGIS Pro.

[FeaturesToJSON_conversion](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/features-to-json.htm#GUID-3CD03573-8039-4DF3-92E4-4FDF42E73556) is well documented as including a parameter for exporting to geoJSON in the new version.  The desktop version of ArcPy does not include this parameter which is why I upgraded.

I receive a 999999 error when specifying `geoJSON='GEOJSON'`. Just to be sure I'm using the right version of ArcPy I confirmed that it **can** take the parameter `geoJSON='NO_GEOJSON'`

I know how to do this with `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON` but I was hoping to stay in ArcPy this week.

---

**This gives error 999999:**

`arcpy.FeaturesToJSON_conversion("lyr", r"G:\GIS_Projects\Backups\json\myjsonfeatures.json", geoJSON='GEOJSON')`

---

**but this works fine:**

`arcpy.FeaturesToJSON_conversion("lyr", r"G:\GIS_Projects\Backups\json\myjsonfeatures.json", geoJSON='NO_GEOJSON')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your ERROR 999999 by running this code snippet:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.management.CreateFishnet(r"C:\Temp\TestProject\TestProject.gdb\PolyFC", "0 0", "0 1", 1, 1, 1, 1,
                               None, "LABELS", "DEFAULT", "POLYGON")
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(r"C:\Temp\TestProject\TestProject.gdb\PolyFC", "PolyFC_Layer")
arcpy.conversion.FeaturesToJSON("PolyFC_Layer", r"C:\Temp\TestProject\PolyFC_FeaturesToJSON.json",
                                "NOT_FORMATTED", "NO_Z_VALUES", "NO_M_VALUES", "GEOJSON")
```

to see:

> Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017,
>   21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "copyright",
>   "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>
> > > > ========================== RESTART: C:\Temp\test.py ========================== Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Temp\test.py", line 7, in 
> > > >             "NOT_FORMATTED", "NO_Z_VALUES", "NO_M_VALUES", "GEOJSON")   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py",
> > > >         line 367, in FeaturesToJSON
> > > >             raise e   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 364, in
> > > >         FeaturesToJSON
> > > >             retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.FeaturesToJSON_conversion(*gp_fixargs((in_features,
> > > >         out_json_file, format_json, include_z_values, include_m_values,
> > > >         geoJSON), True)))   File "C:\Program
> > > >         Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
> > > >         506, in 
> > > >             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
> > > >         Failed to execute (FeaturesToJSON).
> > >
> > > >

Consequently, I think you should report it to Esri's Technical Support as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the FeaturesToJSON tool dose not fully support the [GeoJSON Specification (RFC 7946)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.1 or previous ArcGIS versions.

Here is a output example from ArcGIS Pro 2.1.1 that clearly illustrate how the GeoJSON Specification (RFC 7946) is not fully supported:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "crs" : {
    "type" : "name",
    "properties" : {
      "name" : "EPSG:3857"
    }
},
```

**From Appendix B in RFC 7946 - The GeoJSON Format:**

Appendix B. Changes from the Pre-IETF GeoJSON Format Specification
This appendix briefly summarizes non-editorial changes from the 2008 specification [GJ2008].

B.1. Normative Changes

- Specification of coordinate reference systems has been removed, i.e., the "**crs**" member of [GJ2008] is no longer used.

Comment: Check out :https://github.com/chris48s/arcgis2geojson this python lib is a work around.

Comment: Not yet supporting the RFC 7946 GeoJSON standard:  https://github.com/chris48s/arcgis2geojson/issues/2

Comment: Update: The RFC 7946 GeoJSON Specification is now supported: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arcgis2geojson/